# Skip extra request made by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In a rails application, I do some requests on an external database. In newrelic, when I look at the SQL requests I have this :

```
2.997   718 ms      SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `whale`
3.717   721 ms      SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'character_set_client'
4.440   728 ms      SHOW TABLES LIKE 'whale'
5.169   668 ms      SHOW CREATE TABLE `whale`
5.839   731 ms      SELECT id, `whale`.`name` FROM `whale`
```

As you can see, all requests take a long time so I want to minimize them. I only need the last result.

This is my simple controller :

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    MicsPix.pluck(:id, :name)
    render text: 'ok'
  end
end
```

And my model :

```
class MicsPix < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:otherdb)
  def self.table_name
    "whale"
  end
end
```

Is there a solution to skip queries than I don't use? I don't necessarily want to use ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain where the extra queries arise but i have a suggestion on how to remove them

```
c = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql2",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "root",
  :password => "",
  :database => "mydatabase"
)

sql = "SELECT id, `whale`.`name` FROM `whale`"
res = c.connection.execute(sql)
```

then reset db connection to default.

this code works for me, and I can get results from an external db with only query being executed. I did this in a controller method when I tried it out but I think it would be more neat in the model. As far as I understand the `establish_connection(:otherdb)` does the same as I do when I produce my `c`. So I think you could write something like this in your MicsPix

```
def get_list
  sql = "SELECT id, `whale`.`name` FROM `whale`"
  connection.execute(sql)
end
```

this returns and mysql res object which is quite similar to arrays but not quite.

regards
/Albin

Comment: +1 good example of writing the sql yourself. The extra db requests enable AR to obtain the metadata about the db. Presumably the benefits of AR out weigh its costs. If you just want to do one simple query then you can generate the SQL yourself as shown by Albin.